# Reading CSV file in perl

Tags: perl

I am reading a CSV file using Perl script, I have a CSV file that has Packets in the first column and tag numbers in front of that

Example :

```
Packet0,tag1,tag2,tag3
packet1,tag1,tag2,tag3,tag4
packet2,tag1
```

I have made this script :

```
my @parts = ();
my @tag = ();
my $j=0;
open CSVFILE, 'data.csv';
while (my $row = <CSVFILE>) {
  chomp;
  my @line = split(/\s?,\s?/, $row);
  push @packet, $line[0];

  for (my $i = 1; $i <= $#line; $i++) {
    $tag[$i][$j] = $line[$i]; 
  }
  j++;
}
```

But This code is not working for me , Can anyone help me where I am going wrong ?

Comment: What are your expectations, what it should do?

Comment: It should give me two arrays , @packets , which will contains the packet names and `@tag` which will contains the tag numbers , I have used two dimensional array so that I can store the respective tag numbers of the packets . `tag[packet0][tag1] = tag[0][0] & tag[packet1][tag1] = tag[1][0]`

Comment: You are referring to an array `@csv_line` which is not declared or assigned to anywhere in your code. Also, you are not incrementing `$j`. And more: `chomp` is not affecting your loop variable `$row`, it is affecting `$_`.

Comment: Thanks , Just corrected it but still not reading in a correct manner

Comment: How do you know? You are not printing anything or saving the data.

Comment: Using print command , This is just the part my code

Comment: Well, where and what are you printing and what is the output?

Comment: You should show the print command as well. It is equally likely that you made a mistake in that part of your script. Preferably, you should provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that illustrates your problem for anyone running it. Also, `j++` is not correct code. You should copy/paste the code you are running.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my @packet = ();
my @tag = ();
my $j = 0;

...
while (my $row = <CSVFILE>) {
  my @line = split(/\s?,\s?/, $row);
  push @packet, shift(@line);
  $tag[$j] = [ @line ]; #or push @tag, \@line;
  $j++;
}
...
```

Comment: Better written `push @tag, \@line`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're familiar with the CPAN, there are libraries that solve this problem for you:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV

Doing CSV right can be tricky. Especially when it comes to quoting and multiline fields.

Comment: I second this. Don't let the *apparent* simpleness of the CSV format fool you. The Text::CSV module is easy enough to use and deals well with edge cases.

Comment: Thanks , Just a little query will this `$arrayref = $csv->getline_all ($io, $offset);` solve my problem ? I am going in right direction ?