# Trying to replace a particular column in a set of files with a range of values

Tags: linux, perl, shell

I need to replace a particular Field entries with a range of values.

suppose below are the set of files i have

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
```

and file1.txt has entries like below>>

```
LOI 0403 001900 0000 0100 001 001 000030 000000 00000000 000 PF155000087 0000 PROMO55      
LOI 0403 001900 0000 0100 001 002 000030 000000 00000000 000 0NF18300061 0000 ON           
LOI 0403 002800 0000 0100 002 001 000030 000000 00000000 000 CVCID002100 0000 P41884       
LOI 0403 002800 0000 0100 002 002 000030 000000 00000000 000 CVCID002101 0000 PROMO55      
LOI 0403 004700 0000 0100 003 001 000100 000000 00000000 000 CVCID002102 0000 VERCAR60     
LOI 0403 011900 0100 0100 001 001 000100 000000 00000000 000 CVCID002103 0000 VERCAR60     
LOI 0403 012800 0100 0100 002 001 000030 000000 00000000 000 CVCID002104 0000 VOD88
```

I need to replace the entries from 12th Field which have PF155000087, 0NF18300061, CVCID002100 etc..

similar entries will be available in file2.txt and file3.txt as well.

The above entries must be replaced with a range of entries such as ABCDE000001, ABCDE000002, ABCDE000003, ABCDE000004 etc.. respectively.

upon succesful replacement of file1.txt, the sequence should continue for file2.txt. For example, if the ending value on file1.txt is ABCDE000030, then thst starting of replacement for file2.txt should be from ABCDE000031 and so on...

Can anyone help me on the above scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675773/reading-csv-file-in-perl/21676782). Try to code up something. Add that code to this question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -i -lane '$F[11] = sprintf("ABCDE%06d", ++$i); print "@F"' file1.txt file2.txt ..
```

Comment: As far as I can tell the OP wants the files edited in-place. This makes the changes correctly but sends all of the output in a single stream to STDOUT.

Comment: Okay. I recommend ignoring the reputation system and just doing your best to write good answers. It's more fulfilling that way.

Comment: Yeah tried and observed the same as Borodin has said.  Also instead of providing each file name as File1.txt File2.txt provided the files as *.txt to read all files

Comment: But the o/p is not being written in the files in which it is read. I need to make the replacement directly in te files itself.

Comment: @mpapec: There is nothing wrong with the answer. It was improvised to replace a matching string pattern such that the no. of strings replaced matches the actual. Because, in the actual file each string being repeated more than once. so, tried some improvisation

Comment: @mpapec: Sry for that, i accepted your answer as it is till good. The above trial was done just for improvisation. As per the topic your answer is relevant. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly lengthy solution that uses [`File::Temp`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aTemp) to perform the equivalent of an in-place edit. It writes the modified data to a temporary file, deletes the original file, and renames the temporary file to the name of the original input.

This is all roughly what the `-i` option on the perl command line does (and the corresponding `$^I` variable) but an edit in-place without a backup file is impossible on Windows platforms so this code may be useful to someone.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use File::Temp qw/ tempfile /;

for my $file (qw/ file1.txt /) {
  open my $in_fh, '<', $file;
  my ($temp_fh, $temp_name) = tempfile;

  while (<$in_fh>) {
    my @fields = split;
    $fields[11] = sprintf 'ABCDE%06d', $.;
    print $temp_fh "@fields\n";
  }

  close $temp_fh;
  close $in_fh;

  unlink $file;
  rename $temp_name, $file;
}
```

**output**

```
LOI 0403 001900 0000 0100 001 001 000030 000000 00000000 000 ABCDE000001 0000 PROMO55
LOI 0403 001900 0000 0100 001 002 000030 000000 00000000 000 ABCDE000002 0000 ON
LOI 0403 002800 0000 0100 002 001 000030 000000 00000000 000 ABCDE000003 0000 P41884
LOI 0403 002800 0000 0100 002 002 000030 000000 00000000 000 ABCDE000004 0000 PROMO55
LOI 0403 004700 0000 0100 003 001 000100 000000 00000000 000 ABCDE000005 0000 VERCAR60
LOI 0403 011900 0100 0100 001 001 000100 000000 00000000 000 ABCDE000006 0000 VERCAR60
LOI 0403 012800 0100 0100 002 001 000030 000000 00000000 000 ABCDE000007 0000 VOD88
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this

```
echo $(awk '{print $12}'> *.txt > string_to_replace.txt)
while read -r u3 line1; read -r -u4 line2;
do echo "$line1:$line2"
sed -i -e "s/$line1/$line2/g" file*.txt
done 3< string_to_replace.txt 4< String_replacement.txt
```

Comment: Yeah rt, i missed a * in awk for txt. Thanks